# How to initiate different instance of composer-rest-sever for different business network?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

We have two business network deployed on blockchain network, We would like to initiate two different instance of composer-rest-server on different listening port for different business network running on same fabric network.

Comment: It's not too broad. It's misunderstanding. Kindly refer answer and you may realize that this question is very important and will be very helpful to community.

Kindly open question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of the Composer REST server by using the `-P` argument. For example, to start the Composer REST server on port 9876:

`composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -P 9876`

Using that, you can run multiple instances of the Composer REST server on a single machine or server. Each instance can specify the connection profile and business network to connect to.

Multiple business networks:

`composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -P 9001`
`composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n other-net -i admin -s adminpw -P 9002`
`composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n cool-net -i admin -s adminpw -P 9003`

Multiple connection profiles:

`composer-rest-server -p my-fabric -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -P 9001`
`composer-rest-server -p other-fab -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -P 9002`
`composer-rest-server -p cool-fab -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -P 9003`

A combination of the both:

`composer-rest-server -p my-fabric -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -P 9001`
`composer-rest-server -p my-fabric -n other-net -i admin -s adminpw -P 9002`
`composer-rest-server -p other-fab -n cool-net -i admin -s adminpw -P 9003`

Comment: Thank You Simon :)